# Show Sub categories of products under parent in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm try to find a way to easy manage my categories of products under admin panel.

At the moment all of the categories are list under same location. what I need is when I click on a parent category I can see all of the sub categories and able to add new sub categories.

[image]

Comment: That's howWordPress works. You don't have to click to see the sub categories. You might be able to find a plugin that replaces that admin page; otherwise you'll have to write one yourself.

Comment: Do you know any plugin which might do this.

Comment: No, I don't, and since it's core WordPress functionality to do it this way, I doubt it exists. But maybe someone else knows a solution?

Comment: When you create a category you can set its "parent category". This automatically makes your new category a subcategory. For viewing, perhaps something like [collapsing categories list](https://wordpress.org/plugins/collapsing-category-list) or not sure if this supports categories [collapse subpages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-collapse-subpages/)

Comment: I checked both plugins but they dont meet my needs. I need something which works with woocommerce. I only need to manage in admin panel. I got lot of categories and it makes it very difficult to know whicah cat belows to what. this is why i need this plugin

Comment: i need WooCommerce Admin Category Tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code

```
    add_action('save_post', 'assign_parent_terms', 10, 2);

    function assign_parent_terms($post_id, $post){

        if($post->post_type != 'product')
            return $post_id;

        // get all assigned terms   
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_cat' );
        foreach($terms as $term){
            while($term->parent != 0 && !has_term( $term->parent, 'product_cat', $post )){
                // move upward until we get to 0 level terms
                wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array($term->parent), 'product_cat', true);
                $term = get_term($term->parent, 'product_cat');
            }
        }

    }
```

above code will assign child category product into parent category as well

Comment: I dont wont to assign a category to a product when i'm saving, this is not my problem, my problem is that I need better way to manage my categories in admin panel. I need same functionality as prestashop.com.

Comment: i need WooCommerce Admin Category Tree

Answer (score 1):

for now use the free plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-category-tree/ . Tried and tested it these days and works as intended.

P.S. old question but I was searching for the same answer and havent found any - hope it helps someone else too